# How does Marxist 'alienation' map onto (a lack of) "intersubjective meaningfulnes"?

Tags: meaning-of-life, alienation, intersubjectivity

How does Marxist 'alienation' map onto (a lack of) "intersubjective meaningfulness", how close is the latter to any form of 'alienation'?

I take it that the latter is readily understood: we do not just interact;  I don't just desire to spend time doing so; you do not just amuse me. Because both you and I (or we) exist, our lives are more meaningul, claims of that sort.